# How can I execute commands through python in terminal MAC?

Tags: python, macos, shell, terminal

When I manually run this command in Terminal, it executes, but through Python it gives the error that the **directory is not available** in Python packages.
I am using the following command

```
source ~/trytry/shell.sh
```

Comment: Maybe try replacing `~` with `$HOME`.

Answer (score 1):

This is my test shell file:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo hello
```

when I executed " source ~/test.sh ", it will print hello at console.

This is my python code:

```
>>> import commands
>>> commands.getstatusoutput("source ~/test.sh")
(0, 'hello')
```

It works without any problem. So, would you please show your code?

Comment: my command is this  "source ~/shell.sh" when i launch this trhough terminal manuall it works but through python i am unable to launch this after the exectuion of this command when i write hg pull it start pulling a tree

Comment: Hi bro, I still cannot get your point. Do you mean you write hg pull command in this shell file?

Comment: when i execute this command in terminal manually and after its execution when i write hg pull i pull a source code from TREE  i want to do the same thing through the python script in which it automatically do all these steps

Answer (score 0):

What it looks like to me is that you have a shell script, and not a python file which would have the `.py` extension instead of `.sh`. The error may have to do with the fact that it isn't a python file you're trying to run.